# Activity chooser menu problem : Dialing a number

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

This code makes call successfully from my app

```
Intent dialer = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
mail.setData(Uri.parse("tel:65465446"));
startActivity(dialer);
```

---

But when trying to use an activity chooser like this:

```
Intent dialer = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
dialer.setData(Uri.parse("tel:65465446"));
Intent chooser = null;
chooser = Intent.createChooser(dialer,"Select Dialing Software..."); 
startActivity(chooser);
```

[image: chooser menu]

it throws following Logcat error if I select **Dialer** option, whereas **SkypeOut** works just fine

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  384): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED dat=tel:65465446 flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.PrivilegedOutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{44f4de30 384:com.dialer/10036} (pid=384, uid=10036) requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1298)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onClick(ResolverActivity.java:190)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:874)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>` added

Thanks for your any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to make use of CALL_PRIVILEGED? I think the only difference versus CALL_PHONE is that it can call emergency numbers (65465446 does not look like one). Replace it all with CALL_PHONE and it will work just fine, I believe.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately not working. ACTION_CALL & ACTION_DIAL also doesn't suit my purpose

Comment: It might have something to do with: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10344 - it seems that CALL_PRIVILEDGED is not really available to non-system apps.....

Comment: Please see the first section of my question, It works for me! Also works when I select skype from the menu, only when I select dialer it doesn't work